# list only active root categories with category thumbnails from all the stores in magento

Tags: magento, categories

I have 5 stores in a magento website.

I want to list all the root categories of all the stores with their thumbnail images and link the thumbnail image to the store's home page.

for example:

```
WEBSITE: 
store1 -> category1 
store2 -> category2 
store3 -> category3
```

I have already got the codes working but I am not being able to use addAttributeToFilter() so that I can list only those categories which are active. Currently the following code displays all the root categories whether ACTIVE or NOT.

```
<?php 
    $groups = $this->getGroups(); 
    $cnt = count($groups); 
?>
<?php if($cnt > 1): ?>
    <div class="container">
    <?php foreach ($groups as $_group): ?>            
           <?php 
            $storeId = $_group->getId();
            $store_url = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getHomeUrl();
            $root_cat = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
            $category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($root_cat); // here I used addAttributeToFilter() and gave me error
            $_category = $category_model;
            $_img_path = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/';
            $_no_of_columns = ($this->no_of_columns) ? $this->no_of_columns : 6;
           ?>    

                <?php if ($_i++ % $_no_of_columns == 0): ?>
                <div class="row slide">
                <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getThumbnail()): ?>
                    <div class="span2">
                        <a href="<?php echo $store_url ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>">
                            <img class="img-polaroid" src="<?php echo $_img_path.$_imgUrl; ?>" />
                        </a>
                        <h6>
                            <a href="<?php echo $store_url; ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>">
                                <?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </h6>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>   
                <?php if ($_i % $_no_of_columns == 0 || $_i == $_cat_count): ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>                 
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: "root categories" or "top level categories"?

Comment: No need to shout. Which class is `$this`?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It worked; but I had to use `($_category->getIsActive())` when i used `$category_model->getIsActive();`, it gave me error. What do  i do if I want to filter categories by custom attributes? I donno why $this is used. Its not my code. I took pieces from other sources. I did `$groups = Mage::app()->getStores();`

Comment: You are focused/working in 1 scant fraction of Magento - you should take some time and work through the [Magento for Developers series](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento) by [Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/). There's *a lot* to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using a category model, not a category collection. Models represent one entity and do not have any filters. By `load()`ing the model you are applying all data to the instance, so you should be able to call `$category_model->getIsActive()` to determine if the active flag is no (0) or yes (1).